# antlr4 in dot net "mismatched input 'begin' expecting {';', '+', '-', '*', DIV, MOD}

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, antlr4

I'm using antlr4 in C#.

everything works fine except when i use 'block' everything goes crazy.

for example this is my input code :

```
a:int;
a:=2;
if(a==2) begin
a:= a * 2;
a:=a + 5;
end
```

and this is my grammer :

```
grammar Our;

options{
    language=CSharp;
    TokenLabelType=CommonToken;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

statements  :   statement statements
        |EOF;
statement   :
            expression SEMI
        |   ifstmt
        |   whilestmt 
        |   forstmt
        |   readstmt SEMI
        |   writestmt SEMI
        |   vardef SEMI
        |   block
        ;

block       :   BEGIN statements END ;

expression  :   ID ASSIGN expression
        |   boolexp;

boolexp     :   relexp AND boolexp
        |   relexp OR boolexp
        |   relexp;

relexp      :   modexp EQUAL relexp
        |   modexp LE relexp 
        |   modexp GE relexp
        |   modexp NOTEQUAL relexp 
        |   modexp GT relexp 
        |   modexp LT relexp
        |   modexp;

modexp      :   modexp  MOD exp 
        //| exp DIV modexp 
        |   exp;

exp         :   exp  ADD term 
        |   exp  SUB  term 
        |   term;

term        :   term MUL factor 
        |   term DIV factor
        |   factor POW term 
        |   factor;

factor      :   LPAREN expression RPAREN
        |   LPAREN vartype RPAREN  factor
        |   ID
        |   SUB factor
        |   ID LPAREN explist RPAREN 
        |   ID LPAREN RPAREN
        |   ID LPAREN LPAREN NUM RPAREN RPAREN 
        |   ID LPAREN LPAREN NUM COMMA NUM RPAREN RPAREN
        |   const;

explist     :   exp  COMMA  explist
        |exp;

const       :   NUM 
        |   BooleanLiteral          
        |   STRING;

ifstmt      :   IF LPAREN boolexp RPAREN statement
        |   IF LPAREN boolexp  RPAREN statement ELSE statement ;

whilestmt   :   WHILE LPAREN boolexp  RPAREN statement ;

forstmt     :   FOR ID ASSIGN exp  COLON exp statement;

readstmt    :   READ LPAREN  idlist  RPAREN ;

idlist      :   ID COMMA idlist
        |ID;

writestmt   :   WRITE  LPAREN explist RPAREN ;

vardef      :   idlist COLON vartype;


vartype     :   basictypes 
        |   basictypes LPAREN NUM RPAREN 
        |   basictypes LPAREN NUM COMMA NUM RPAREN ;

basictypes  :   INT 
        |   FLOAT 
        |   CHAR 
        |   STRING 
        |   BOOLEAN  ; 


BEGIN         : 'begin';
END           : 'end';
To            : 'to';
NEXT          : 'next';
REAL          : 'real';
BOOLEAN       : 'boolean';
CHAR          : 'char';
DO            : 'do';
DOUBLE        : 'double';
ELSE          : 'else';
FLOAT         : 'float';
FOR           : 'for';
FOREACH       : 'foreach';
FUNCTION      : 'function';
IF            : 'if';
INT           : 'int';
READ          : 'read';
RETURN        : 'return';
VOID          : 'void';
WHILE         : 'while';
WEND          : 'wend';
WRITE         : 'write';

LPAREN          : '(';
RPAREN          : ')';
LBRACE          : '{';
RBRACE          : '}';
LBRACK          : '[';
RBRACK          : ']';
SEMI            : ';';
COMMA           : ',';

ASSIGN          : ':=';
GT              : '>';
LT              : '<';
COLON           : ':';
EQUAL           : '==';
LE              : '<=';
GE              : '>=';
NOTEQUAL        : '!=';
AND             : '&&'|'and';
OR              : '||'|'or';
INC             : '++';
DEC             : '--';
ADD             : '+';
SUB             : '-';
MUL             : '*';
DIV             : '/'|'div';
MOD             : '%'|'mod';
ADD_ASSIGN      : '+=';
SUB_ASSIGN      : '-=';
MUL_ASSIGN      : '*=';
DIV_ASSIGN      : '/=';
POW             : '^';

BooleanLiteral : 'true'|'false';

STRING : '\"'([a-zA-Z]|NUM)*'\"';

ID : ([a-z]|[A-Z])([a-z]|[A-z]|[0-9])*;

NUM : ('+'|'-')?[0-9]([0-9]*)('.'[0-9][0-9]*)?;

WS  :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip ;

COMMENT : '/*' .*? '*/' ;

LINE_COMMENT : '//' ~[\r\n]*;
```

when i run the parser i get the following error message :

no viable alternative at input 'if(a==2)begina:=a*2;a:=a+5;end'
mismatched input 'begin' expecting {';', '+', '-', '*', DIV, MOD}
no viable alternative at input 'end'

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your rule for a list of statements:

```
statements : statement statements | EOF ;
```

This rule has two options: a `statement` followed by another list of `statements`, or `EOF`. The only non-recursive option is the `EOF`, which becomes a problem when you use this in your rule for a `block`:

```
block : BEGIN statements END ;
```

You can never encounter `EOF` in the middle of a `block`, so when the parser reads the line before the `end` in your sample input, the next thing that it expects to read is another `statement`. The word `end` on its own isn't a valid `statement`, which is why it throws the error that you are seeing.

One possible fix is to make the recursive part of your `statements` rule optional:

```
statements : statement statements? | EOF ;
```

This will allow your sample input to parse successfully. In my opinion, a better option is to remove the recursion altogether:

```
statements : statement* | EOF ;
```

Finally, you can see that the `EOF` is still one of the options for the `statements` rule. This doesn't make much sense when you use this rule in the as part of the rule for `block`, since you shouldn't ever find an `EOF` in the middle of a `block`. What I would do would be to move this to a new top level parser rule:

```
program : statements EOF ;
statements : statement* ;
```